# Rewrite sql to support joins

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have the following query which in oracle databases should work but current wordpress instalation uses a mysql database. Could you please help me out to rewrite the next query so it will work on mysql ?

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, DAYOFMONTH(b.meta_value) as dom "
."FROM $wpdb->posts a, $wpdb->postmeta b "
."WHERE b.meta_value >= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-01 00:00:00' "
."AND b.meta_value <= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-{$last_day} 23:59:59' "
."AND a.post_type = 'post' AND a.post_status = 'publish' AND a.ID = b.postid AND   b.meta_key='Event Date'"
);
```

Comment: If wordpress allows you to use query parameters, do so.  Send date values instead of strings.  Also, I would change the <= some date 23:59:59 to < the day after that day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a problem with the date format of the constant.  I would suggest converting the date into the same format using `to_char()`.  I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, to_char(b.meta_value, 'DD') as dom "
."FROM $wpdb->posts a, $wpdb->postmeta b "
."WHERE to_char(b.meta_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') >= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-01 00:00:00' "
."AND to_char(b.meta_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') <= '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}-{$last_day} 23:59:59' "
."AND a.post_type = 'post' AND a.post_status = 'publish' AND a.ID = b.postid AND   b.meta_key='Event Date'
```

Or, more simply:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, to_char(b.meta_value, 'DD') as dom "
."FROM $wpdb->posts a, $wpdb->postmeta b "
."WHERE to_char(b.meta_value, 'YYYY-MM') = '{$thisyear}-{$thismonth}' "
."AND a.post_type = 'post' AND a.post_status = 'publish' AND a.ID = b.postid AND   b.meta_key='Event Date'
```

This assumes that `meta-value` is stored as a date.  If not, you have to deal with conversion of values into dates.  I'm making this assumption because you are using a function `DAYOFMONTH`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an issue with your query in MySQL from what I can tell.  Both of the following statements produce the same results (although I prefer to use the `JOIN`).  Here is a simplified version:

```
SELECT  *
FROM table1 t 
    JOIN table2 t2 on t.id = t2.id
WHERE t.dt >= '2011-01-02 00:00:00';

SELECT  *
FROM table1 t, table2 t2
WHERE t.dt >= '2011-01-02 00:00:00' 
   AND t.id = t2.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5aba6/3)